# How can I gather a sqldatasource's results as a comma separated string in code behind?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

Hello and thank you for your time. If I have a Sqldatasource that is pulling from my database a list of ID's based on a certain criteria, how can I call that list formatted to a comma separated string in code behind? For example, say this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT ID FROM MyDatabase WHERE Email <> ''
```

Results being:

```
   | ID |
   ------
   | 16 |
   |  2 |
   | 81 |
   |  4 |
```

How can I call call that in code behind as a comma separated list with no trailing comma like below?

```
16,2,81,4
```

Comment: I've tried putting it into an array, then using String.Join, but it didn't come out the way I wanted. I also tried attaching the datasource to a Dataview and using [this method.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I wasn't able to get it to work quite right. Edit: Thanks Pleun, I'll give that a quick search!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (For in code behind):

Fill the data in datatable and access each data using for loop and concat string.

```
 For iRowIdx = 0 To dtblData.Rows.Count - 1
  Result += dtblData.Rows(iRowIdx)("ID") + ','
 Next
```

Instead you can combine the values in SQL:

```
SELECT 
   STUFF(
       (SELECT ',' + CAST(ID as varchar(max)) 
        FROM (SELECT ID 
        FROM MyDatabase) AS B FOR 
            XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') 
    AS ExpectedResult
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can do is to use a `Datareader`. This will allow you to cycle through the records being returned from the query and access all of the values in the code behind.

You can use it like this,

```
    command = new sqlcommand("Select ID from [Test]", conn)
    datareader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While datareader.Read()
        'Access the Columns here
    End While
```